# Why can't you downvote your own question?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question earlier today:

[Function clash when implementing multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436352/function-clash-when-implementing-multiple-interfaces/21437293#21437293)

It was, in my opinion, well-posed but the answers made me realise that what I was asking was illogical. Of course, in the interests of the folk replying, it would *not* be good if I could delete the question as that would remove their gained reputation points. But I would like to signal to the community that the question is a poor fit to the knowledge base that SO is aiming to build: why should other folk be relied upon to do that? I would be willing to sacrifice a reputation point for the downvote for this sake.

Of course, upvoting your own question will lead to many problems, but I am not asking for that: just the ability to downvote.

I will, of course, be wanting to downvote this question too if it turns out that, on inspection of any replies, what I'm asking here is *also* illogical.

Comment: Ha. Someone just upvoted it ;-)

Comment: You can't vote on your own posts. Period.

Comment: Up. Yes I understand. But why not *down*? Unusual; granted.

Comment: Downvote it for you ;-)!

Comment: Lets say you downvoted the question, you do know that there's a counter that counts for downvotes and ban you eventually, it's like banning yourself - committing suicide :)

Comment: Btw dow-voting questions doesn't actually cost rep, just answers.

Comment: If you want downvotes that badly, just come to meta and ask for them!

Comment: If you think there is a problem with your question, then why not address the problem? If you can't, just leave it.

Comment: You could always cast a close vote on it.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName if I would see such Meta commentary in a question, I would go in and remove it. It's not part of the question, so it simply shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Bart Good point; edited.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: you legend! If you are willing to be my anti-sockpuppet for ever then I withdraw this idea.

Comment: @Bathsheba No problem! Ping me and I'll be your downvoter! (But I respect the rule in regard of serials downvoting and I'll downvote only if I agree with you that your question is bad :P )

Comment: I have sometimes thought this would make sense for meta feature requests. For when you no longer agree with your past self

Comment: This raises an interesting question, if someone has a split personality, can he downvote his other persona?

Answer (score 13):

Because it's impractical to spend programmer time on a use case that will never be used.

Comment: BUT.. Downvoting questions doesn't cost you rep, so why not! It's free!

Comment: Then it might be *abused*, @Amal. Downvote your own *good* question and some might feel pity for you and upvote? (And then remove your own downvote, of course.)

Comment: @Arjan: It was supposed to be a funny comment. I failed :-|

Answer (score 1):

If YOU want to down-vote your own question, you don't need to worry ... there will be TONS of down-votes (because the question probably deserve it).

Also, cost to spend on this change (code)